# Do devices on AC currents have flicker on and off?

Tags: ac, solid-state-devices

For current to alternate between positive and negative it must be zero for a split second. Does that mean devices receiving AC current are flickering on and off? This seems like it would have some bad effects.

Comment: An ac motor does not momentarily stop between cycles and an incandescent lamp still emits although the latter does no because it cannot cool down instantaneously in the short period of zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. More precisely, AC current is a sine wave, and so the voltage and current smoothly pass through zero. In a purely resistive load, the current and voltage are in phase, and the power into the load can be described by the absolute value of \$\sin(t)\$. In reactive loads, the current will lead or lag the voltage, but both the current and voltage still pass through zero at some point.

For simple resistive loads, this is fine e.g. an incandescent light bulb receives pulses of power, but its time constant is much greater than 1/60Hz, so you don't see a visible flicker. Another example might be a slow cooker, which also has a time constant *much* greater than the line frequency.

For many devices (phone chargers, computers, etc), we use AC/DC converters that convert the alternating current to a steady DC current.

Several types of motors actually depend on the alternating current, as it determines their rotational speed by alternating the current through the windings.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, AC power crosses zero 100 or 120 times per second, depending on where you live.

Some people say they can see the flicker if a lamp is of a type that will get significantly dimmer after a millisecond of power loss, (LEDs, neon and fluorescents, not incandescents or HID lights). Because of this, many lamp drivers/ballasts include capacitors or chokes so they can supply continuous power across the voltage drop.  Electronic fluorescent ballasts raise the AC frequency dramatically, so there is no chance of you seeing the flicker.

When a broken fluorescent light is dim and obviously flickers, that's not the 100/120 Hz effect, that's a problem with the bulb or ballast.

Comment: "_Because of this, many lamp drivers/ballasts include capacitors or chokes so they can supply continuous power across the voltage drop._" I think you are confusing the function of fluorescent power factor correction capacitors. The supply would have to be rectified before capacitors could be used to "supply continuous power across the voltage drop". In fluorescent lamps there are no rectifiers.

Comment: That's why I used the weaselword "many".  To defeat the 120Hz flicker, you must either a) supply the lamp DC, or b) supply the lamp at a much higher frequency.  I think you are talking about magnetic ballasts which can't do either one, so outside the scope of the "many".   Anyway they are not only obsolete but near extinct given that electronics have elbowed them out in the market, and power companies pay people to replace em (cheaper than building more generators).  Here's an interesting page that shows the rectifiers and PFC:  http://sound.westhost.com/lamps/fluoro-lamps.html

Comment: "_That's why I used the weaselword "many"._" I find myself doing the same thing and avoiding absolute statements. It's a tough neighbourhood! ;^)